# Conditional loading of Dojo modules

Tags: dojo

Let me first present directory structure of what I have

```
/
├── dojo/
├── dojox/
├── dijit/
└── app/
    ├── a/
    │   └── moduleA.js
    ├── b/
    │   └── moduleA.js
    └── c/
```

I'm trying to configure Dojo to be able to load `moduleA.js` in following way:

```
require(["app/moduleA"]
```

and in the same time resolve it according to below pseudocode:

```
if moduleA exists in c
    load "app/c/moduleA.js"
else if moduleA exists in b
    load "app/b/moduleA.js"
else if moduleA exists in a
    load "app/a/moduleA.js"
else
    standard fail, same as when no module is defined
```

It would be great if order `a`, `b` and `c` could be passed as array for instance `["app/c/moduleA", "app/b/moduleA", "app/a/moduleA"]`.

I was looking into documentation hoping to find something, but no luck. https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/loader/amd.html#module-identifiers was closest I got. There is packages.location property, but it takes string to load module, so I guess it has no additional logic regards to arrays.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please look at this https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/has.html

Comment: Are you trying to implement this client side? `require` will fail if it can't load a module or file.